# Map for Spider-man 3 meteorites and spider emblems?

Tags: spiderman-3

Could anyone link me to the locations of all the meteorites and spider emblems in Spider-man 3 for PS2 (not for other systems). The image I keep coming across is this:

[image]

but when I go to those locations in my game they are not correct, and also the island looks different in that map than in my in-game one.

I know there is [a game guide](http://www.neoseeker.com/resourcelink.html?rlid=150431&rid=139425) for this also, but my computer is not in the same room as my PS2, and the guide is way too big to print.

Comment: We're not here for custom asset requests.  If there's a solution already available to you, it's up to you to make it work, in my opinion.  Can't you just print the relevant sections of the guide?

Comment: 1. That's why I asked for a link to one.
2. The entire guide is prevalent minus the intro.

Comment: It is literally the first result when doing a Google image search for "Spiderman 3 map"

Comment: Sheesh, ok I edited it so that I'm only asking for a link to a map.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Spiderman 3 Map]

[Taken from IGN forum post by user Violentpcfst](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/the-official-spider-emblem-search-thread.141440683/page-3)

Comment: Same map I linked to....

Comment: @Guy Not really, check again. Also, I'd imagine this is probably about as accurate as you're going to get.